# android call resource file by his name

Tags: android, bitmap

Hello I'm a new to android and I'm trying to display a photo base on a id (number between 1 and 52) I have in my resource folder pictures of 52 card with a name of ic_1 to ic_52
and i need to be able to create bitmap from them base on a id i tried do this (card.getId() give the id number between 1 and 52)

```
String cardView = "R.drawable.ic_"+card.getId();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Integer.parseInt(cardView));
```

but it didn't worked any help would be welcome thanks.

Comment: This code will throw a NumberFormatException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the ID this way:

```
int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_"+card.getId(), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use getIdentifier()

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_" +card.getId(), "drawable", getPackageName());
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
```

Answer (score 1):

to get the int value of your resource you need to use getIdentifier method.

```
String mDrawableName = "R.drawable.ic_"+card.getId();
int resID = getResources().
            getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```